# How to make show a character counter for several textareas in same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML form with several textareas.
I need to limit the number of characters for each area.
I want to shouw a counter.
I found this on the web:

```js
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        
      var characterCount = $(this).val().length,
          current = $('#current'),
          maximum = $('#maximum'),
          theCount = $('#the-count');
        
      current.text(characterCount);
     
            
    });
```

```css
    #the-count {
      float: right;
      padding: 0.1rem 0 0 0;
      font-size: 0.875rem;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Displaying The Character Count of a Textarea</h1>
      <textarea name="the-textarea" id="the-textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..."autofocus></textarea>
      <div id="the-count">
        <span id="current">0</span>
        <span id="maximum">/ 300</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**MY PROBLEM:**

It works for 1 textarea but then stop to work when having several text areas. How to transform the javascript function in order to make it work for any text area and counters in the page?

Comment: that's probably because duplicating the textareas you are duplicating also their ID so you end up with more than one object with the same id and thus is invalid and leading to such a behaviour. You have to dedup the IDs to make it work for all. The same applies to all the other items that have an ID if you are duplicating them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on all the inputs and then attach a `oninput` event listener, like this:

```js
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

textareas.forEach(textarea => {
  textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var charCount = textarea.value.length;
    var count = textarea.nextElementSibling;

    count.innerHTML = charCount + ' /300';
  })
})
```

```css
#count {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.1rem 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Displaying The Character Count of a Textarea</h1>
  
  <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus></textarea>
    <div id="count">0 / 300</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus></textarea>
    <div id="count">0 / 300</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus></textarea>
    <div id="count">0 / 300</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In pure Javascript.

Comment: Nice solution! @barhatsor

Comment: Thanks a lot. @barhatsor

Comment: I have an issue with the maxlenght display. with your solution it is fixed. I have different maxlenght for different textareas. How to fix this issue please?

Comment: While this works, the uniqueness of `id` still applies and should be dealt with appropriately.

Comment: For example `getElementById('count')` will always return the first occurance of `div#count`, no matter where you use it. `id` shall be unique, whether you like it or not and whether you need it or not. Yet do not be confused with just setting no `id` at all, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, you can. And no, you should **not**. Since you like MDN, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) you go.

Comment: Right. No two same id's in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

ID's should be unique. Give different id's. It will work.

CSS:

```
#textCount, #textCount1 {
  padding: 0.1rem 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Displaying The Character Count of a Textarea</h1>
    <textarea id="textarea1" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..."></textarea>
    <div id="textCount1">
        <span id="current1">0</span>
        <span id="maximum1">/ 300</span>
    </div>

    <textarea id="textarea2" maxlength="300" placeholder="Start Typin..."></textarea>
    <div id="textCount2">
        <span id="current2">0</span>
        <span id="maximum2">/ 300</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#textarea1').keyup(function() {
    
  var characterCount = $(this).val().length,
      current = $('#current1'),
      maximum = $('#maximum1'),
      theCount = $('#textCount1');
    
  current.text(characterCount);
 
        
});

$('#textarea2').keyup(function() {
    
  var characterCount = $(this).val().length,
      current = $('#current2'),
      maximum = $('#maximum2'),
      theCount = $('#textCount2');
    
  current.text(characterCount);
 
        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Textareas with different `maxLength` value.

`id` issue also resolved by making it `class`

Make modification from other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64375096/2385565).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e8fhL1b/)

Code

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Displaying The Character Count of a Textarea</h1>
  <div>
     <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="450" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus> </textarea>
    <div class="count">0 / 450</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="400" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus></textarea>
    <div class="count">0 / 400</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <textarea name="textarea" maxlength="500" placeholder="Start Typin..." autofocus></textarea>
    <div class="count">0 / 500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
let textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

textareas.forEach(textarea => {
  textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    let charCount = textarea.value.length;
    let count = textarea.nextElementSibling;
    let maxLength = textarea.maxLength;
    count.innerHTML = charCount + ' / ' + maxLength;
  })
})
```